# std::vector<char> to std::string

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to convert a `std::vector<char>` into a string using:

```
//  Data has been received, update the buffer...
buffer = readBuffer.data();
buffer[bytesRead-1] = '\0';
```

The issue I am having is that when I debug readBuffer I get `"<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>."`

but on reviewing buffer I get `'<A HREF="https://ww ²²²²▌▌╫$Ö►¬∟☺.google.com/">here</A>.'`

Is there something really obvious I missing?

Comment: Vector is defined as std::vector<char> readBuffer(size); Wont readBuffer.data() return array of chars?

Comment: It returns a pointer to the first element of the `vector` (assuming `size != 0`). You probably haven't shown the line of your code that has the error. What does "reviewing" mean? I assume you access `buffer`, but when? Does `readBuffer` still exist when you review `buffer`?

Comment: @SteveJessop I suspect that the OP's `buffer` pointer outlives the `readBuffer` vector, which causes it to point to deallocated data. This would cause garbage to show up when reviewing (inspecting the contents of) `buffer`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Writing a null character at the end of a character vector will not magically create an `std::string`. To create an actual `std::string`, use something like:

```
std::string s = std::string(readBuffer.begin(), readBuffer.end());
```

You don't need to explicitly append the null character to the string, the `std::string` constructor will do it for you.

Comment: Thank you.. fixed.  I appreciate your fast answer, i didn't realise it was possible to call that constructor like you did.